# What does it mean when a mission is illegal?

Tags: elite-dangerous

When taking missions some of them have a special listing as "this action is considered illegal". What exactly does that mean for me? Will I get a bounty on my head for taking it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, they're asking you to be a smuggler.

Ultimately it will mean two things while you're carrying that cargo:

1. You will need to do a sneaky station entry, unless it's an outpost.
2. You will need to avoid being scanned by any system authority ships, such as if one interdicts you.

If a system authority ship (including those orbiting a station entrance) does the kind of scan that shows up as a "scan alert" while you're carrying the illegal cargo, you'll get a fine. If you don't pay the fine within 24 hours it will turn into a bounty (and you'll be wanted in that system). Being caught with illegal cargo will give you a bad reputation with the local system authority faction.

If you're unlucky enough to get caught with the illegal cargo in multiple systems, you could end up with multiple fines. I believe if you're caught again by the same authority (interdicted and scanned then enter a station they control), you won't actually get fined a second time for the same illegal cargo containers.

Note that some missions that *don't* have that warning, are actually for commodities that might be illegal in other systems.

Comment: Got scanned carrying military plans that that faction had asked me to retrieve and got an 80,000cr fine and "unfriendly" with the Federation... Fine didn't go up when I got scanned again entering the station.

Comment: You should edit your answer rather than adding a comment

Answer (score 1):

It involves performing actions that are illegal and will get you bounties if caught, like attacking Clean ships in non-Anarchy systems or transporting cargo that's illegal in certain systems (such as Performance Enhancers and Slaves).

The mission itself won't get you a bounty, but completing it just might cause you end up with a fine or a bounty on your head if you're not careful.

Comment: It will get you fines, not necessarily bounties. Though, I suppose the two go hand in hand.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so adding an answer to correct Cmdr Freiheit's answer.

It is possible to be scanned at an outpost, I've had it happen twice, one time whilst carrying illegal cargo.

In both cases the outposts were aligned to the Alliance, but I'm not sure if that means that there are no Federation or Empire outposts that will scan you.  In both cases there were a lot of contacts on my scanner unlike usual approaches to outposts where there are generally none (I play in private groups so I rarely encounter other human commanders).

Getting past security at a patrolled outpost is a lot more difficult than at a normal station.  With a normal station if you start to get scanned you can get through the letterbox/entrance quickly enough to break the scan.  This is not possible at an outpost and in my experience it is often a lot harder to find or approach your landing pad at an outpost.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: As mentioned in the first line, I didn't have enough rep to comment. I do now, though!