# What happens if I am caught bringing prohibited goods into a station?

Tags: elite-dangerous

One of the missions for naval progression wants me to bring combat stabilizers to them, except combat stabilizers are illegal in pretty much all jurisdictions. What happens if I get caught bringing them back? Do I get a bounty on the spot? Does the station initiate lethal response?

Comment: [related, but not dupe](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201047/what-does-it-mean-when-a-mission-is-illegal?rq=1)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answer:
You never get shot on sight for smuggling, instead it is an instant fine.

Additional info:
The fines are usually a lot higher than the value of the goods that you are smuggling, meaning that you really don't want to get caught.

If you don't pay the fine within a certain time (which was 24 hours last time I checked), it gets converted into a Bounty and, if I remember correctly, you become wanted by the faction that issued the fine.

The easiest way to avoid being fined is to smuggle into an Outpost, at which there are usually - but not always - no patrolling security ships (it is the security ships that scan you, not the station), however be warned: Outposts that do have security ships are harder to smuggle to than normal stations because you are always visible.  With a normal station you can usually break the scan by flying through the station entrance.

Obviously, if you are smuggling for a mission, you don't have the luxury of choosing where you smuggle to, you have to return to the station that issued the mission.  There is a lot of advice on the internet about how best to avoid being scanned.  Personally I keep about 8KM away from the station entrance, lined up ready to dock already having requested permission.  I disable everything except my thrusters, scanner and power distributer.  I boost to get to full speed then cruise towards the station at max speed.  When getting close, I hit Silent Running, turning it off as soon as I get into the entrance as well as hitting reverse and dropping the landing gear to slow down.

I've never got a fine with my method, although a couple of times I have had a scan start as I'm nearing the entrance.  It doesn't work well for all ships - some don't slow down fast enough as you go through the entrance and some overheat too quickly for the silent running.  You just have to find a system that works well enough for you.

Comment: Additional thoughts:

Comment: Bah, edit time limit: As far as I am aware, you won't get scanned if you are smuggling to an Anarchy station.  It may be the case that there are no authority ships around to scan you.  BEWARE: A system that is classed as Anarchy can still have some stations in it that are not Anarchy.  I've fallen foul of this myself just after Gamma started.

Comment: Yeah you tend to only get shot on sight for actually having shot someone else or hitting someone near the station. 

I don't think you get shot for dumping cargo - just fined. It's only agressive acts that get you shot up

Comment: Aggressive acts, and parking violations.